# Using Threads to extract some files

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have a  problem. I need work with files in some folders and extract all to one folder.

My problem is that the threads lost or not work correctly.

```
Product lstProduct = new Product();

lstProduct = XML.LoadProducts();
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

for (int i = 0; i < lstProduct.Length; i++)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExtractFiles));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    threads.Add(thread);
}

for (int i = 0; i < threads.Count; i++)
{
    threads[i].Start(produtosConfiguracao[i]);
}
```

Calling Function:

```
public void ExtractFiles(object config)
{
    Product product= (Product)config;
    try
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Int32.Parse(product.Threads),    Int32.Parse(product.Threads));
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(product.Path);
        List<FileInfo> lstFiles= di.GetFiles(product.Type).Where(o => o.Extension == ".zip").ToList();

        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo lstFiles)
        {
            lock(this)
            {
                FileProduct fileProduct = new FileProduct();
                fileProduct.File= fileInfo;
                fileProduct.Product = product;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ExtractAndMove), fileProduct);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would simply comment that it's unlikely that operating multiple threads to perform IO work is going to result in a performance boost. In fact, it's more likely to cause a performance slow-down, depending on how many concurrent threads you have running. The threads will all be competing for IO which is going to be your bottleneck.

Comment: Yep unless the extraction is CPU bound, throwing extra threads/concurrent reads at the problem is simply going to cause IO congestion and slow things down rather than speed them up.

Comment: also you are in a public instance method so its saffer to declare a private object member variable to serve as the lock token.

Comment: This code probably just deadlocks.  A hard requirement for an STA thread is that it must pump a message loop.  Trying to run the extraction code on a TP thread is wasted effort, COM marshals the calls on the FileProduct object back to the STA thread.  Well, it tries anyway.  Just don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the *Async overloads of the I/O functions and using async/await in 4.5 if you can. You're trying to do something here that the operating system does for you via IOCP.